# PHP preg_split - match whitespaces, apostrophes, backticks

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I've got following string from INPUT POST textarea:

```
' 123
'123
'' 123
''123
`123
` 123
```

I'd like to convert it to the following array:

```
[0] => 123
[1] => 123
[2] => 123
[3] => 123
[4] => 123
[5] => 123
[6] => 123
```

I'm trying with this but I don't know how to combine all of them in one regular expression:

```
\ ('+)('+\s+)(`+)(`+\s+) \
```

It doesn't seem to work as expected.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you written any php code ?

Comment: `trim($string, ' \'\`');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
preg_match_all('/\d+/sim', $text, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

and if you want to iterate over matches

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result[0]); $i++) {
    # your cleaned data = $result[0][$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `trim()` and feeding it the characters it needs to remove. In this case it would look like:

```
trim($inputString, ' \'`');
```

Depending on the exact situation, you may want to loop through the inputs and perform this action, then use `array_push()` to add the value into an array.